# Using Parceable to pass Objects in android

Tags: java, android

Wrote a class that helps pass my object, was working fine until i wanted to pass a  more generic object myself.

```
public class StepParceble implements Parcelable {
private Step mStep;
private JSONObject mStepData;
private onScreen mOnScreen;

public StepParceble(Step step, JSONObject stepData, onScreen onScreen) {
    setmStep(step);
    setmStepData(stepData);
    setmOnScreen(onScreen);
}

public StepParceble(Parcel parcel){

}
public onScreen getmOnScreen() {
    return mOnScreen;
}

public void setmOnScreen(onScreen mOnScreen) {
    this.mOnScreen = mOnScreen;
}

public void setmStep(Step mStep) {
    this.mStep = mStep;
}

public void setmStepData(JSONObject mStepData) {
    this.mStepData = mStepData;
}

public JSONObject getmStepData() {
    return mStepData;
}

public Step getmStep() {
    return mStep;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    try {
        dest.writeArray(new Object[]{mStep, mStepData,mOnScreen});
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public StepParceble createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new StepParceble(in);
    }

    public StepParceble[] newArray(int size) {
        return new StepParceble[size];
    }
};
```

}

it return a null pointer on getting any of those values.

Passing the data as

```
StepParceble stepParceble = new StepParceble(step, stepData, onScreen);
            Intent uiIntent = new Intent(context, UIActivity.class).putExtra(UiControlTrier.STEP_KEY,stepParceble);
```

Comment: If you are fine with using a third party library use `EventBus` from green robots

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide means to read fields from your parcelable when you've overridden the constructor

```
public StepParceble(Parcel parcel){
//add methods to populate fields from parcel
}
```

You can use Android Studio plugins to do this for you:
https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin

Also, if your class has complex-type fields (like Step in your case), those should be Parcelable too